# Is it possible for a function to ever return a value different from its explicit return values?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

```c
int my_func(void) {
    if(/*condition*/) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (/*other condition*/) {
        return 2;
    }
    
    return 3;
}

int x = my_func();
```

Is `x` GUARANTEED to always be one of the 3 possible values?
Provide proof in the form of a quote from the Standard or POSIX or some other legitimate source. If there is no such source, provide logical proof (gcc/assembly).

Comment: It's more of an a priori proof.  If you only have three `return`s, then one of them has to be used.

Comment: What else could this function possibly return besides 1, 2 or 3 -- and how would that happen?  But I suppose if you are up against some strict environment -- like coding for medical equipment -- then yes you really need to know the details to the extreme.

Comment: What if one of the conditions triggers some fault, e.g. a signal like SIGABRT or SIGSEGV?

Comment: Then presumably the function doesn't return at all.

Comment: you guys are being all cute, but I'm serious. I need to know if I have to explicitly check for all 3 return values or if I can infer that if the return value is not 2 out of the 3 values, that it is then 100000% the third value always

Comment: There's no point checking the values because if you can't trust the return statement, then you also can't trust any if statement you use to do the check.

Comment: The only problem in trusting the third value is when you add another condition and return statement to the function ... and forget to change **all the relevant code**.

Comment: @sneaker -- it can be a daunting thing to find the C Standard docs (it was for me).  I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) helps and that you quickly and easily find your answer.

Comment: Presumably, in some environments, you could insert code into those conditions that jumped to yet another function that returned a value outside the expected set, but that is not C standard:)

Comment: Hi @sneaker, Don't be put off. If Eric Postpischil is defending you, you're in good company (IMHO). Experienced programmers will write code where they assume in this case that if you've checked 2 of the 3 possibilities then it's the 3rd. I think some of the negativity you're getting is that people don't even see it as a question. But as a novice at some point you do need to learn that (with qualifications) computers are deterministic and that kind of reasoning is applicable. "When you have eliminated all which is impossible then whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth".

Comment: @sneaker out of curiosity - what do you need that answer for? Some sort of formal verification for high-safety software? Academic research on that? Homework? Some coding guideline that needs to be added/overridden? Some of the comments here might have been written in a funny manner, but they raised valid issues. Nothing wrong with the question itself, but setting it in a context of an actual problem might allow way better answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most important statement in the Standard is:

> If a `return` statement with an expression is executed, the value of the expression is
> returned to the caller as the value of the function call expression. If the expression has a
> type different from the return type of the function in which it appears, the value is
> converted as if by assignment to an object having the return type of the function.

So if one of the `return` statements is reached the relevant value is returned.

Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77250845/4213662) provides reasons why it may be that none of them is reached including a call to `abort()` or `exit()` in a function called in the actual `if` conditions.

The code has placeholders (e.g. `/* condition */`) and those could execute code  or call functions beyond simple conditional logic.

In this answer I'm picking out the essential points in the Standard that justify the main conclusion.

So on the proviso that the executed conditions are guaranteed to evaluate (not terminate the program or execute indefinitely) the definition of an `if` statement is the only other thing required to establish that one of those values is returned:

> In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression
> compares unequal to 0. In the `else` form, the second substatement is
> executed if the expression compares equal to 0.

Where it says 'both forms' it is referring to the plain `if` and `if`-`else` forms.

Both forms appear in the example. There's an `if`-`else` and `else` statement is itself an `if` statement.

Beyond that it's more logical deduction than a statement of the C standard to conclude that (if the function returns) in a program with defined behaviour(*) it must return one of those 3 values (1, 2 or 3).

(*) Not containing anything that has undefined behavior.

Ref: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Comment: *"`abort()` or `exit()`"* they void all `return` value deliberations.

Comment: @0___________ Yes. But the question asks if `x` is guaranteed to be one of the values. There are a number of reasons why it might never be assigned any value. One of the other answers covers that case but doesn't mention those functions.
For example, the conditions could call functions which could themselves call those functions and never themselves return.

Comment: 1. If program terminates then it makes no sense to discuss what will be the value of `x`. If function never returns then the value of `x` does not matter  as the code will never get to the place where it will be used. If all returns are skipped (longjump for example) then use of `x` will invoke UB. All are nonsense in the scope of this question

Comment: @0___________ It depends how you read the question. "Is x GUARANTEED to always be one of the 3 possible values?" is pretty emphatic. I'd say it's relevant to point out that it's not guaranteed it will be anything at all. If we added 'printf("%d",x)` and asked if the output was always guaranteed to be 1,2 or 3 it would definitely be valid to say "or nothing".

Comment: Nice, thoroughly answered.  TBH, I really didn't think we'd find return value specifically called out in the standard.  I don't know why?  I guess it seems trivial -- like "of course!"  Which is the attitude many of us *seemed* to take, initially anyway.  Thank you.

Comment: @Kz2023 Thanks. I'm pleasantly surprised by how much positive response my answer has received. It's easy to reply "Well duh! Obvs." but it's sometimes a worthwhile exercise to go back to the source materials and see how far you can go to *prove* what we all agree is an obvious conclusion. If all that does is familiarise people with the Standard for when they have a 'real' question. I added the 'language-lawyer' tag and if you're serious about Software Engineering I think you should be at least comfortable with the is question and the source documents.

Answer (score 8):

There are some other possibilities:

- it might never return (e.g. infinite loop, segfault)
- inline assembly can cause returns too
- it could do a long jump to some other code
- In C++ you could have an exception
- undefined behaviour can cause basically anything to happen

But in general yes, `x` must be one of the returned values.

This has nothing to do with POSIX.

One notable form of undefined behaviour is reaching the end of a function that should return but doesn't. This is not even a warning with GCC by default:

```
int foo(int a) {
  if (a == 1) { return 1; }
  if (a == 2) { return 2; }
}

foo(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

## ***Yes, it is guaranteed.***

If it did not, then C language could not be used for anything other than playing Russian roulette

Other things stated in another answer and comments like UBs, cosmic rays, jong jumps, voo-doo and other programming hacks and errors do not change the general rule.

> Provide proof in the form of a quote from the Standard or POSIX or
> some other legitimate source.

I do not think that your function will be listed in the standard. But any compiler has to produce the same observable behaviour of your program. The Standard does not have to provide such a guarantee as it is logical that the program is being executed as it was written by the programmer.